# Move shipping section to the right side of woocommerce checkout page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been struggling to change the layout of my woocommerce checkout page. I'd like to move the Shipping details to the right, so it's side-by-side with the billing. I was able to move the order details section to the right side via CSS but I also want the shipping to move there, just above the order summary and I can't seem to do it in CSS.

[image: sample image]

Comment: Please share your relevant code here.At Stack Overflow, we need to include minimum relevant code with the question.If, you include your code, I will be able to help more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have to override the WooCommerce checkout form.**

### How to override:

Copy the checkout form from the path `plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php` and paste in your activated theme (for e.g. here I'm pasting it inside my customized child theme of WordPress official theme `twentytwenty`) in the following path `themes/twentytwenty-child/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php`

---

### Override the content like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Checkout Form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', $checkout );

// If checkout registration is disabled and not logged in, the user cannot checkout.
if ( ! $checkout->is_registration_enabled() && $checkout->is_registration_required() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message', __( 'You must be logged in to checkout.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
    return;
}

?>

<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <?php if ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields() ) : ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>

        <div class="col2-set" id="customer_details">
            <div class="col-1">
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review_heading' ); ?>
    <div class="col2-set">
        <div class="col-1">
            <h3 id="cus-shipping-heading">Shipping Details</h3>
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php esc_html_e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review' ); ?>

    <div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review' ); ?>

</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', $checkout ); ?>
```

### Explaination of the changes:

1. Removed the shipping section from the `div#customer_details`
2. Add that section next to the action hook `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review_heading' ); ?>`
3. Here is the snippet of the section we added:

`<div class="col2-set">
    <div class="col-1">
        <h3 id="cus-shipping-heading">Shipping Details</h3>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>
    </div>
</div>`

---

### After the change the checkout page will look like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks, this actually works. Though I had to change the path to <YourChildTheme>/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php. Basically added the "templates" in the path, same as the source path. Thanks again!